# MySQL Workbench cannot load mysql.proc

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am starting to use MySQL Workbench tool especially for data modeling. So, the first I would like to do is reverse engineering of my existing database on web server. But I not able to finish the process, because I alway get this strange error message:

```
Error: Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
```

I tried to repair this table but it not help me. So, do you have any experience with this problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: i have the same problem with a straight install mysql 5.6.  I tried the mysql_upgrade -uroot -p but it didnt help.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.9 on MAC. I fixed this problem by running:

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

Comment: Where do you run this command? I can't seem to run this command from Terminal shell or in mysql. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm running MySql using MAMP - the command is in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade

Comment: If you're still wondering where to run this command, this is what worked for me. I had MAMP running, then opened Terminal and typed in "mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force". At the password prompt, I entered the password for my MAMP. (This is typically 'root', I think.) Then all was fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin! I had exactly the same issue but after upgrading mysql, the problem was fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: For WAMP, running this in a windows command prompt worked:
"C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin\mysql_upgrade.exe" -uroot -p

Comment: I had the same issue and the solution worked. However the problem i had was that when the password was prompted for I was giving the wrong password (didnt knew it changed) and the message thrown was "Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed"...This got me confused. so please be aware that if you get that message pls re-check your password.

Comment: You may need `sudo` instruction if mysql is installed with macport.

Comment: Does Workbench need MySQL installed locally if I wanna use it just to connect to a remote db server?

Answer (score 11):

I'm using MySQL trough MAMP Pro, and Kevin's answer didn't work for me.
Yes, I had to do a ***mysql upgrade*** BUT I had to use the following commands on the Terminal:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/repairMysql.sh
/Applications/MAMP/bin/upgradeMysql.sh
```

This worked for me.
Hope this can be helpful to somebody else..

Answer (score 4):

I used XAMPP in CentOS and manually upgraded the XAMPP except the existing data folder.
With the new server software of MySQL and old database files, I got the same error.

I did with this solution and worked fine:

```
cd /opt/lampp/bin
./mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

It looped through almost all tables in the system, but ended with a fixed issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Centos 6.5 for Server purposes. And Mysql Workbench for ERR Diagram. I got the same error. Answers above did not work for me.

This answer is based on changing data type for comment column. And works like charm.

Connect mysql from console.

```
use mysql;
show create table mysql.proc;
```

Then look for *comment* column. If it's datatype is char, change to text.

You can also use any other gui for making changes.

Comment: How you figured this out I don't know, but it helped me fix an older CentOS install!

Comment: Glad to hear @grandmasterb

Answer (score 2):

On windows, with XAMPP i managed to fix the issue by going to the directory:

`C:\xampp\mysql\bin` and running the executable `mysql_upgrade.exe` you'll find inside, make sure your mysql server is running.

Comment: This one worked for me in Windows 7 , stop and start you mysql Server

Answer (score 1):

I use MAMP on mac and failed to upgrade the my databases via command line as suggested above, but it worked when i used MAMP PRO->TOOLS menu options (top of OS X screen) to 'Check', 'Repair' and 'Upgrade' databases.

I presume that the GUI supplies the underlying CLI tools with the necessary options, so that you don't have to think about what those options need to be (as opposed to running the CLI tools manually).

Upgrading my MAMP in this way (via MAMP PRO's GUI Tools) made my (separate) Oracle mysqlWorkbench 6.0 app work just fine with my local MAMP PRO 2.0.5 databases on OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion), which mysqlworkbench had said were corrupt previously (but MAMP's phpmyadmin worked fine on them whilst they were "corrupt", curiously). Now, both mysqlWorkbench 6.0 and MAMP PRO's phpmyadmin tools are both happy, and so am I.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force`

You may need to specify the full path for command if *mysql* it's not in the shell's search path.

On Debian 6 it should be loaded with:

`/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force`

On Mac's MAMP the default path is:

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force`

On Windows it'll be where MySQL is installed and contained in the bin subdirectory. By default it should be located at:

`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server\[*CHANGE TO MySQL SERVER*]\bin\mysqladmin" -u root shutdown`

Original resource: [How to Resolve MySQL Error Code: 1548 Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted](http://www.myguysolutions.com/2013/10/30/how-to-resolve-mysql-error-code-1548-cannot-load-from-mysql-proc-the-table-is-probably-corrupted/)

Answer (score 1):

If this happens on a specific query, be aware that this can also happen when you try to use an undefined function.

Comment: Thanks, this was what happened to me. Using `STR_TO_TIME` instead of `STR_TO_DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to schema changes required for different server versions.

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

will filx the issue.

Sometimes you require to uninstall server and clean its data directory. And re-install to make a fresh copy of data files.

Answer (score 0):

Using MAMP PRO (version 2.2) I tried pmking's suggestion and was still getting nowhere. So I edited the two files:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/repairMysql.sh
/Applications/MAMP/bin/upgradeMysql.sh

changing 'proot' to 'p' in each. This creates a prompt for the MySQL root password and it worked!

I hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

on debian 6, MySQL 5.1.73-1 (Debian), I had the same problem, and a start and stop helped me.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

not sure what happen, but the problem seems to go away after this quit stop and start, just wanted to add it here, in case others have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, when I had a syntax error in my SQL query in a join.

I did

`JOIN shops ON s (...)`

instead of the correct

`JOIN shops s ON (...)`

This error was really confusing, I don't know what this has to do with mysql.proc, but fixing the query fixed the problem. None of the above solutions worked for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens when the changes in schema required different versions of mysql server.

To fix this, follow the line of codes below:

```
mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force

/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force
```

Complete details of post will find here: [Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted](http://unlimitedwebworks.guru/web/cannot-load-from-mysql-proc-the-table-is-probably-corrupted)

Answer (score 0):

if you're on Unix based (like Ubuntu) you can try this :

```
sudo ./mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
```

like Bimal suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same error, and solution was just stupid, so I recommend to look for simple answers before starting to upgrade stuff. In my particular case the problem was I did:

```
COUNT (id) AS quantity ... # Fails: notice space between COUNT and (
```

where it should read

```
COUNT(id) AS quantity ... # Works: notice no space between COUNT and (
```

This happens when you don't use a framework, you could (should) do something like this, in this case with in [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) 5:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, i just go to C:\xampp\mysql\bin and run mysql_upgrade.exe

It repair itself and now everithing is working great.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.6\bin>mysql_upgrade --force -u root -p`

This force upgrade worked for me.