# "Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted" on Osx / homebrew

Tags: mysql, corrupt

Problem:

Getting `Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted` when trying to create new mysql user.

**Platform**: OSX Yosemite, Homebrew

Tried all the below and **DID NOT WORK**:

1. Upgrading: [`mysql_upgrade -uroot -p`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6874553/163382)

   - I had to use `--force` because of this: `This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.9, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade`
   - Next I had to use `--skip-version-check` because of this: `Error: Server version (5.7.18) does not match with the version of the server (5.7.9) with which this program was built/distributed. You can use --skip-version-check to skip this check.`
   - still didn't work after all that
2. Reducing the query to most obvious and [taking out functions](https://serverfault.com/a/672538): `CREATE USER 'newuser';`, still throws same error.
3. Repairing the mysql.procs_priv table
4. Changing all the `char` columns in `mysql.procs_priv` to `varchar`, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29237997/163382). Well he suggested changing to `text` but that seemed too crazy for a core mysql table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely removing mysql and reinstalling it worked (less than 15 mins).

**1. UNINSTALL AND PURGE MYSQL FROM SYSTEM**

1. Back up databases.
2. Stop and kill any MySQL processes. Check for processes with `ps -ax | grep mysql`
3. Uninstall mysql

   ```
   brew remove mysql
   brew cleanup
   ```
4. Remove all the residual files

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
   sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
   sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
   sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
   ```
5. Unload previous auto login

   ```
   launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
   ```
6. Remove previous config. Delete the line `MYSQLCOM=-YES-` from `/etc/hostconfig`
7. Remove previous preferences

   ```
   sudo rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
   sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
   sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
   sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
   sudo rm -rf /private/var/mysql
   ```
8. Optional, restart computer. I didn't.

**2. INSTALL MYSQL**

1. Install Mysql

   ```
   brew install mysql
   ```
2. Set to run on startup

   ```
   brew services start mysql
   ```
3. Secure the installation

   ```
   mysql_secure_installation
   ```

Comment: worked for me. I think my install was messed up because of trying out MariaDB

Answer (score 9):

I think it will be better to use this:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Enter your password and wait a few seconds.

Comment: This worked perfectly and I didn't have to reinstall mysql!

Comment: If there is a log after running ```mysql_upgrade```, it is easier to troubleshoot the specific reason. ReInstall is the last resort.

Comment: I just used this method, after that, it allowed me to create the user and grant privileges....

Comment: This worked perfectly with OSX v10.15.7 and mariadb v10.6.3. Had to perform a restart of the system after that.