# Mailtodisk do not extract email in mailoutput folder

Tags: php, email, xampp

I want all emails to be written in mail mailoutput folder in xampp folder. I have configured the mailtodisk.

Here is my php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port=25
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=On
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789373/mysql-workbench-cannot-load-mysql-proc

Comment: no this issue that you write is about Mysqlworkbench and my issue is in droping database.

Comment: But your table is corrupted. It doesnt matter which action throw this error. here another article http://www.myguysolutions.com/2013/10/30/how-to-resolve-mysql-error-code-1548-cannot-load-from-mysql-proc-the-table-is-probably-corrupted/

Comment: Where to find this table please can you help me?

Comment: Do you have full access to the server?

Comment: Yes i have full access to my server what should i need to do?

Comment: try at first to execute `mysql_upgrade -uroot -p` if you have linux or mac

Comment: i have done the upgrade of the mysql and now when i try to drop the database central i got this error SQL Error (1010): Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.\central', errno: 41 "Directory not empty")

Comment: This question no longer even remotely resembles the original question, please do not abuse the edit feature like this.

Comment: Hello  BMitch please can you help me because i need to make new question but i am blocked!